# Remove a tab in Ribbon in Excel for Mac

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-js

I have made an add-in ("Funfun") by myself. The manifest files are a little bit messy. Curiously, I cannot remove that add-in from Ribbon anymore in Excel for Mac.

I tried to "reset all customizations", and to re-install Excel, but the `Funfun` tab is still there. As a consequence, I cannot load the right manifest file to debug that add-in.

[image]

Does anyone know how to remove that tab, and start from the very beginning?

Answer (score 1):

According to Excel for Mac documentation:

Remove tabs: You can remove custom tabs only from the Ribbon. To remove, select your tab in the Customize the Ribbon box and click  Office 2016 for Mac Customize Ribbon Remove Button

Ref: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/customize-the-ribbon-and-toolbars-in-office-for-mac-26911d4c-4971-41cd-b606-5fbc0318f499

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the Office cache to clear out the record of custom buttons and tabs. Details can be found here: [Changes to add-in commands including ribbon button and menu items do not take effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/testing-and-troubleshooting#changes-to-add-in-commands-including-ribbon-buttons-and-menu-items-do-not-take-effect).

Comment: I tried to remove `/Users/{your_name_on_the_device}/Library/Containers/com.Microsoft.OsfWebHost/Data/`, it did not work...